# Problems with undefined variable in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I keep getting Undefined variable: cars when loading the page in Laravel.

I have the following code:

web.php

```
Route::get('/cars', function () {
    $cars= Car::select('brand')->get();    
    return view('test.cars')->with(compact($cars));
});
```

If I put `dd(cars);` before return view the collection is outputted.

In cars.blade.php I have the following code:

```
<select name="car">
@foreach($cars as $car)
    <option>{{ $car->brand}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

and I get Undefined variable: cars, I also removed the dropdown from blade template and I tried `{{ dd($cars) }}` but get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code :

```
Route::get('/cars', function () {
    $cars= App\Car::pluck('brand');    
    return view('test.cars',['cars'=>$cars]);
});
```

OR

```
Route::get('/cars', function () {
    $cars= App\student::pluck('first_name');    
    return view('test.cars', compact('cars'));
});
```

Note: Car model is present in App folder here.

Comment: Thanks seems that I was returning compact($cars) and it should be compact('cars').

Comment: @RickinRathatha yes exactly compact() is not a Laravel function. It is a PHP function. It creates an array containing variables and their values.

Comment: @RickinRathatha please vote up if my answer helped you as you expected so that others can reach to this issues easily.

Comment: Sorry as i'm a new user my rep. doesn't allow me to upvote yet!

Comment: Oh got it! Enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for passing variables to views is either:

```
view('test.cars', ['cars' => $cars])
```

or

```
view('test.cars')->with('cars', $cars)
```

the "with" function requires a name to be passed first, followed by the variable.